How to TypeCheck JavaScript Files like VSCode does in Problems Pane
I would like to be able to run from the command line something that replicates the output VSCode provides for my project files in the "Problems" pane when I open them as described in their docs section "type-checking-javascript".
Their problems section includes eslint suggestions which I can reproduce in my terminal for the same file or my whole project with something like eslint .. For the ts errors I thought that I could do something like:
tsc -p tsconfig.json --noEmit --skipLibChecks

Where my tsconfig.json file is like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "compiled",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

That should run through all my project files and do the same. Instead it reports errors from imported libraries in node_modules. It also doesn't report errors in my original project files found by VSCode in "problems" pane.
There is a lot of discussion on Stack Overflow on related things to this but none answer my question. It is suggested that --skipLibCheck will help ignore some non-js files and the "exclude" section of tsconfig.json will also stop the checker from looking at that directory. However my understanding is that if one of my files imports a file from node_modules, the typechecker will then look at that file as well. There is no way around this.
But that doesn't explain why issues in my original files are not being reported (unless there is a max amount of issues the console will return or these imported files are breaking the checker). It also leaves me scratching my head, if the VSCode app can do what I want, isn't there some way I can replicate that? Or is Microsoft doing some magic that no one knows how to replicate?
Other things I've tried
I've tried using different versions of tsc: version 3.8.3 which I have installed globally. I've also tried the version 4.4.4 in my project at node_modules/.bin/tsc. I've tried variations of the above tsc command with different params.
Advice, insights corrections welcome.
